# How do i make my Gridview clickable

Tags: android, xml, json, gridview, layout

I have this gridview and i want it to start seperate activities once they are clicked.
For example my GridView has name and image of Theaters. So once i click a particular theater shown in the gridview it should redirect and show details of that theater. How can i achieve this?

TheaterFragment class

```
package com.fortuna.cinemalk;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.fortuna.cinemalk.adapter.LazyAdapter;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.model.BaseElement;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.CommonVariable;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.service.JSONServices;
import com.fortuna.cinemalk.util.Element;

public class TheaterFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> filmTheater;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theater_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            filmTheater = JSONServices.getTheater();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(filmTheater);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(filmTheater, activity,
                    Element.THEATER_LIST.getType());

            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

}
```

theater_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

theater_list_layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:background="@color/tabDark"
           android:gravity="center"




         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/theaters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@color/tabDark"
        android:textStyle="bold" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class TheaterFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;

    private ArrayList<BaseElement> filmTheater;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theater_fragment, container,
                false);

        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity,theaterDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("theaterInfo",passtheaterinfodatahere);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            filmTheater = JSONServices.getTheater();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        /* check again */
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            commonVariable.setTheater(filmTheater);

            adapter = new LazyAdapter(filmTheater, activity,
                    Element.THEATER_LIST.getType());

            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what should i put in "passtheaterinfodatahere" ?

Comment: which i just given demo can you please let me know how can you show theater info in details ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(TheaterFragment .this.getActivity(),OtherActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } 

        });
```

Comment: after gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

Comment: what is it? Intent i = new Intent(TheaterFragment .this.getActivity(),OtherActivity.class); do you replace OtherActivity.class with your intended activity and also dose that activity declare in manifest

Comment: i did declare in the manifest. i included my logcat in your answer.can you take a look

Comment: i changed it to MovieDetailFragment.class

Comment: Sorry but first do learn some basic, do not worry you can not replace by that because that is not ACTIVTY, it is FRAGMENT and you can not call fragment, each fragment must associate by activity. and in the intent you must call activity not fragment. do search and learn these !!!

Comment: so what should i do to call that fragment class?

Comment: lot of steps that i can not tell you in comment, search internet or read fragment doc on google